# R, determine shortest path

Tags: r, shortest-path

I have a graph and need the shortest distance between all nodes.
Now I made the following function,

```
shortestPath <- function(streets, length)
{
    streets <- matrix(streets, byrow=TRUE, ncol=2)    # from -> to
    g <- graph.data.frame(as.data.frame(streets))     # create graph, see plot(g)
    return <- shortest.paths(g, weights = length)     # return routes lengths
}
```

Here `streets` is a vector which contains data where we have an edge and `length` is (obviously) the length of the edge.

I have the following graph where each edge has length two, note that the graph has to be undirected.

[image: Given graph]

You can use the following data to reproduce the problem.

```
# Data
edges <- c(1,2, 2,3, 3,4, 4,5, 2,6, 3,7, 4,8, 6,8);
length <- rep(2,8);
aantalNodes <- 8;

# Determine shortest path
routes <- matrix(shortestPath(edges,length), byrow=FALSE, ncol=aantalNodes);
```

We clearly see that the shortest path between node 6 and node 8 has length 2, however, this function returns length 4. What's going wrong? I'm already tinker with it for two days. Looking forward for you help!

Comment: I think the problem is that your function has an argument named  `streets` while according to the body of the function, that argument should be named `edges`. In the future, please make your example reproducible so we can actually answer the question rather than speculate at best.

Comment: I see that I indeed made a typo in my question. I will give data such that is reproducable in a hour.

Comment: So you still have a problem? If so please provide the `streets` and `length` inputs to make your example reproducible. Also, be careful that `length` is also the name of a function, hence a very bad name choice for a variable.

Comment: Yes I still have a problem. This typo was only in the function here and not in my R document. You can find the data such that you can reproduce it. Furthermore, I will change the variable name `length`. Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the rownames and colnames of `shortestPath(edges,length)`. It's really rather revealing...

```
res <- shortestPath(edges,length)
res[order(as.integer(rownames(res))),
    order(as.integer(colnames(res)))]
```

Comment: +1 - I edited so the solution can handle graphs with 10 or more vertices.